# error: cannot find symbol class AsyncCallWS Android

Tags: java, android, web-services

I'm trying to rewrite the application in this, in Android Studio [link](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-webservice-example/), which is written in Eclipse. There are two problems, first problem is there is this line in the project :

```
import com.example.webserviceactivity.R;
```

I couldn't write this one on Android Studio. 
The second problem is, in this part of the code  :

```
b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //Button Click Listener
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Check if Celcius text control is not empty
                if (et.getText().length() != 0 && et.getText().toString() != "") {
                    //Get the text control value
                    celcius = et.getText().toString();
                    //Create instance for AsyncCallWS
                    AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                    //Call execute 
                    task.execute();
                //If text control is empty
                } else {
                    tv.setText("Please enter Celcius");
                }
            }
        });
```

I have this error :

> error: cannot find symbol class AsyncCallWS Android
>   in this part :

```
AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
```

How can I solve these problems? Thanks.

Comment: What is AsyncCallWS? Have you import it?

Comment: Check my answer. Accept it if it works for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the link you post, I see a class like below. Create this class in your project before using it.

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
            getFahrenheit(celcius);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
            tv.setText(fahren + "° F");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
            tv.setText("Calculating...");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove import statement from ur code or replace `com.example.webserviceactivity` with ur package name.

Second copy `AsyncCallWS` class from given link and put on your activity class or create same class on ur project.